# C# ASP.NET application using ldap for authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, openldap

Trying to authenticate through ldap using LdapDirectoryIdentifier to communicate to an openldap server.

Code snippet

```
dapDirectoryIdentifier ldi = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("ldap.com", 636);
LdapConnection lconn = new LdapConnection(ldi);
lconn.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
lconn.Bind();
lconn.Dispose();
```

Running the code gives me an exception at Bind() stating LDAP server is not available. But upon reviewing my netstat, the connection is there and established. There are no other error messages available.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 636 is for SSL. Try directly with LdapConnection to make sure you can access that server via SSL (SecureSocketLayer = true):

```
using (var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection("my.ad.server:636")) {
                    var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, "my.ad.server");
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
                    ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
                    ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
                }
```

See if this works.

Comment: This was partially the answer. There was also no certificate so I had to circumvent that using lconn.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback((con, ver) => true);